# CS0121 errors using DryIoc when migrating from PCL to netstandard Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0, dryioc

I needed to migrate a Xamarin.Forms project from PCL to .netstandard. I use the PCL compatibility nuget package to consume PCLs referenced in the project but I am having a problem with DryIoc that I'm not sure why it is happening. I figured maybe someone here has seen this and can help. Basically I'm getting CS0121 errors (call is ambiguous between 'method1' and 'method2' ) One of the errors is below. I replaced part of the path with the ~ but it looks like it is confused with itself.

~/.nuget/packages/dryioc/2.12.7/contentFiles/cs/any/Container.cs(56,56): Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DryIoc.ReflectionTools.GetFieldOrNull(System.Type, string)' and 'DryIoc.ReflectionTools.GetFieldOrNull(System.Type, string)' (CS0121) (Masterflex)

Thanks!

Comment: Try use "DryIoc.dll" package instead of DryIoc source package.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by replacing the `PackageReference` of DryIoc with a `Reference` node in the csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="DryIoc">
  <HintPath>..\packages\DryIoc.dll.4.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\DryIoc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```